# Why can't I connect to my other windows server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking

I have two dedicated servers on local lan Workgroup (no domain controller) : I have activated file sharing etc. but I can't access the other pc.

When I do IPConfig I can there they do not have same default gateway. Is this the reason ? Why if yes, how to fix this (knowing I am renting these servers on a hosting service so I don't have physical control on them).

Comment: Providing the actual ipconfig outputs would help in determining if the IP configurations are actual factors here.

Comment: I cannot give the ip for security reason. IP config shows nothing special (mask 255.255.255.0)

Comment: Are they on the same /24 IP net/plan? If so, can they successfully ping each other?

Comment: not sure to understand their ip are the same on first 6 chars. They sure can ping each other since they're accessible from internet and can access internet but through LAN I don't know how to test it cause I'm novice.

Comment: How about across the octets (between the periods)?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into issues with address resolution.  If you're trying to "access the other pc" by UNC path (i.e. \server2\path) you probably didn't setup any way for server2 to find server1.

In a normal closed network by default... windows uses netbios to elect a master browser which can hold the names & ip addresses of servers in the same broadcast domain, and provide them to other peers in the same network that request them.  In a virtual hosting service, frequently the servers aren't in the same broadcast domains, and admins go to a great deal of effort to keep the servers from being able to identify each other.  It's possible that they prevent netbios all together.

A simple work around... would be to setup a few static entries on both servers using the [lmhosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMHOSTS) file or the [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOSTS) file to provide address resolution.  Keep in mind also, that many anti-virus packages might identify messing with either of those files as something bad.

Comment: @Cheekaleak lmhosts has nothing to do with WINS.  And yes, 2008 and 2008R2 both have WINS support as well as the ability to use a LMHOSTS file.

Comment: I was thinking of IPv6 support for WINS/ Netbios name resolution. Long day...

Comment: @cheekaleak  I know the feeling.  And yes... no IPV6 for WINS/Netbios as far as I know.  I am not sure if lmhosts would work or not with ipv6... might be interesting to try it out.  Of course... Trying to read war & peace backwards sounds more interesting.

Comment: hello I don't understand my server are virtual server it's physical machines.